# How to Display Two JTables in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have two JTables that I would like displayed in one window. Currently I am able to display only one of the tables using:

```
JTable table1 = makeTable(1);
JTable table2 = makeTable(2);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(table2);
frame.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.validate();
frame.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//frame.add(scrollPane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(700, 500);

frame.setVisible(true);
frame.validate();
```

What is the simplest way to display multiple tables, one on top of the other (though orientation is irrevelant) using Swing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add both JTables to the same position in the BorderLayout.

What you can do is the following:

```
frame.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(scrollPane2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.validate();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Is there a way to position the elements more precisely?

Comment: Have a look at the Layoutmanagers: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html But I am not a big fan of the existing LayoutManagers. Maybe you could have a look at JGoodies. They even look nice ;) http://www.jgoodies.com/

Comment: The most precise one is GridBagLayout, but examine other layouts managers before using it, sometimes it is an overkill.

Comment: You might also consider a JSplitPane for this one.  That puts the 'precise control' directly into the hands of the end user.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of Prine, I found a solution that met my needs. For anyone looking for a rudimentary scheme to achieve this sort of layout:

```
JTable table1 = makeTable(1);
JTable table2 = makeTable(2);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Container c = frame.getContentPane();
c.setLayout(new BoxLayout(c, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
c.add(table1.getTableHeader());
c.add(table1);
c.add(table2.getTableHeader());
c.add(table2);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```